# Creating New Foreign Key (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I am having a bit of trouble creating a foreign key in my DB. Here is a paraphrased model of what my tables look like:

**NOTE**

```
 * (PK) NOTE_ID   BIGINT
 *      TITLE     VARCHAR(200)
 *      DATE      DATETIME
 *      SERIES_ID BIGINT
```

**SERIES**

```
 * (PK) SERIES_ID BIGINT
 *      TITLE     VARCHAR(200)
 *      DESCR     VARCHAR(1000)
```

I am trying to create a "has a" relationship between `NOTE` and `SERIES` by `SERIES_ID`. I thought that setting up a foreign key between the two tables by `SERIES_ID` would be the solution, but when I attempt to create it I get the following error:

> ERROR: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.SERIES' that match the referencing column list in the
>   foreign key 'FK_*SERIES*_NOTE'. Could not create constraint

I'm using the web database manager that comes with the GoDaddy SQL Server I set up, so I'm not sure what the underlying query it's trying to use or I would post it.

At the end of the day, this is all to create a relationship so that the NHibernate mappings for my Note object will contain a one-to-one relationship to a Series object. I may not even be trying to tackle this the correct way with the foreign key, though.

Am I going about this the correct way?

**EDIT:**
In an attempt to pair down the tables to a more simple example, I removed what I thought to be  several non-critical columns. However, I ended up leaving a field that was actually a part of the composite primary key on the series table. So, because I was trying to assign the foreign key to only one part of the composite key, it was not allowing me to do so.

In the end, I have taken another look at the structure of my table and found that I don't actually need the other piece of the composite key - and after removing, the assignment of the foreign key works great now.

Comment: Without the **actual T-SQL statement** being generated, it's really hard to say anything.... most likely that web manager does something wrong - or you're picking the wrong columns or something.....

Comment: @Tyler, From an NHibernate perspective, and a database perspective, that is not a one to one relationship.  It's a many to one relationship.  It would be a one to one relationship if both the primary keys were `NOTE_ID`.

Comment: You've marked `SERIES_ID` as a primary key in `SERIES`, but have you checked that this is actually so? A lot of people confuse primary keys and identity columns - they're two separate concepts. If possible, does the manager application you're using let you generate scripts for existing objects? If so, adding the actual table definitions rather than your pseudo-definitions would be useful.

Comment: Totally agree with what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said. It doesn't actually have to be a PK, but it does at least have to have a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you may try running the following statement in a query analyzer and see the resulting error message (I guess @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right ) :

```
ALTER TABLE NOTE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SERIES_NOTE 
FOREIGN KEY (SERIES_ID) REFERENCES SERIES(SERIES_ID)
--ON DELETE CASCADE
-- uncomment the preceding line if you want a delete on a serie 
-- to automatically delete all notes on this serie
```

Hope this will help